# python: what things should i take care when pinging to more than 3000 IP address

Tags: python

I have to write something to ping more than 3000 IP address every time(nonstop) and i should check if an IP has not respond to ping `x` times in a row, report it to operators. I do not know what kind of subjects i have to take care of: such as resource checking, threading or processing, using celery or RabbitMQ(since i do not have any experience working with them) or anything else? I seriously do not have a clue to start from where?

I appreciate any idea in advance.

Comment: You mean simultaneously?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Do you *have* to reinvent this? There are lot of excellent monitoring apps (including free, open-source ones) already out there, e.g. [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/), [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/), [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) to name a few.

There are lots of problems you will come into doing it yourself, some ideas that come immediately to mind:

- Running out of resources on the monitoring box itself (i.e. *it* is starved of CPU / network to do all that monitoring). This shouldn't be a problem for those numbers, but at greater scale it would be.
- Dealing with multi-threading in your Python app. It's always hard, especially when things go wrong.
- [Dealing with flapping](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/flapping.html) of these services (possibly less of an issue just for pings).
- "Who monitors the monitor?"
- Firewalls / routers ditching responses to pings on healthy boxes.
- Detecting higher-level issues for that machine (i.e. pings still responding, but everything else useful on that machine is dead, out of disk, etc).

If you *do* still want to do it yourself, I'd start with a basic doing [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) using a round-robin approach.

You could try scheduling these tasks with [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) (but can be quite hard to understand / debug), or go straight to multi-threading. As you say, using an [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol)implementation like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) would be good to allow persistence (so you can restart your python program, etc), but sounds a bit like overkill to start with.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I think it takes much more effort than i thought it would. Maybe i have to use SNMP in this situation.